# SQL joining two columns on two strings

Tags: sql, string, oracle, join

I am trying two join two columns on certain strings.  The only problem is that one for one of the columns contains a lot of text, and the string I want to join on is in the middle of this text.  For example:

Column_a (from table_a) contains:  x

Column_b (from table_b)contains:   tuv xyz abc

I want to be able to join on "x".  What can I use to accomplish this?
  Here is my basic code.

```
select 
    *
from (
    select 
    *
    from table_a

) ta
left join (
    select 
        *  
    from table_b 
) tb 
on bd.person = ttp.login 
and ('tuv: ' || ta.column_a like '%tuv: %' || tb.column_b || '%')
```

This returns no result, the two tables will not join.

Comment: What  database type? MySQl? SQLServer? etc.

Comment: is `table_a.columns_a = 'x'` if not what does "contains" mean?

Answer (score 2):

Concatenate the shorter string with the wildcard symbols and then use `LIKE` against the longer string. Note double-ended wildcards searches are not efficient and this will be an "expensive" query.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d7ce9/1)

**PostgreSQL 9.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_a
    (Column_a varchar(20))
;

INSERT INTO table_a    (Column_a) VALUES    ('x');


CREATE TABLE table_b
    (Column_b varchar(20))
;

INSERT INTO table_b    (Column_b) VALUES    ('tuv xyz abc');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select 
    *
from table_a a
left join table_b b on b.column_b like ('%' || a.column_a || '%')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d7ce9/1/0)**:

```
| column_a |    column_b |
|----------|-------------|
|        x | tuv xyz abc |
```

Comment: I used Postgres because it supports the double pipe for concatenation, but so do other databases such as DB2 and Oracle. Please **always tag** your sql related questions with the **actual database type** you are using

Comment: "*but so do other databases such as*" - or any database that respects the SQL standard

Comment: I will try this.  Sorry for not adding what database I am using.  It is Oracle, by the way.  First time poster as well :)